# Populate new item form with info from page

Tags: 2010, list, form, item

Is it possible to populate this new item form with information already filled in another form?

In this example, I have customized the default new item form to include a webpart to another list.

[Screenshot](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_0VRZGDRGRS-f9FsClQekP1z4-HZTDeBxLcnc_QQQ6U=w905-h554-no)

Many thanks.

EDIT: This is for SP 2010

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript on the "Product Request" form you can change the "new item" link so that the resulting new item form is prefilled. See [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43335/40006) about prefilling fields in newform.

For filtering existing items list you could add a querystring filter webpart to the product request form and use the ID parameter to filter on a lookup column in the items list webpart